# How to creditmemo for order with Total paid 0 amount

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I have an order with total paid amount is 0 after applying discount. After complete there is no creditmemo button showing for that order.

Order total showing in below figure :

[image]

How to create creditmemo for that order?

Comment: Answer of this post is :
[Order Status after creditmemo is complete for order with 0.00 total](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105949/order-status-after-creditmemo-is-complete-for-order-with-0-00-total)